# Typesetting equations but results in error in tabularx

Tags: amsmath, tabularx

I am using tabularx as follows with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \noindent 
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lYY S[table-format=1.4] @{}}  

\toprule 

\thead[lc]{a}& \thead{$(0,0)$} & {\thead{$(\frac{2}{3},\frac{15k-10}{9k})$}} & {\thead{$(k,0)$}} \\

\midrule  

$0<k<\frac{2}{3}$ case with $k=\frac{1}{2}$ & Saddle Point at $(0,0)$ & Saddle Points at $(\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{-5}{9})$ & Stable Node at $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ \\ \addlinespace

$k = \frac{2}{3}$ & Saddle Point at $(0,0)$ & 0.72 & 0.72 \\ \addlinespace  

$\frac{2}{3} < k < \frac{7}{3}$ case with $k = 1$ & 0 & 0.37 & 1.00 \\ \addlinespace  

$k^{*}\approx 1.2667$ &a & a& a\\ \addlinespace

$k^{*} < k < \frac{7}{3} \text{ with } k = 2$ &a &a &a \\ \addlinespace

$k = \frac{7}{3]$ &a & a& a\\ \addlinespace

$k > \frac{7}{3}$ with $k=3$ &a &a &a \\ \addlinespace

\bottomrule  

\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I'm not exactly sure why I get an error saying emergency and latex does not let me compile this code. The error is as follows: 'File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.
<*> newfile1.tex'

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

Could someone please help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: There are several issues (missing `\begin{document}`,  a stray `\noindent`, ...) and a typo: `\frac{7}{3]` instead of `\frac{7}{3}`.

Comment: You have an entry `Stable Node at $(\frac{1}{2},0)$` in a column of type `S[table-format=1.4]` but LaTeX expected a numeric there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `\frac{7}{3]` in the last but one row.

How do you debug this problem? Comment all table rows and then uncomment them one by one until you find the one that produces the error.

However, when you fix that issue, you discover that the fourth cell in the second row contains material that's not good for an `S` column, but that's for you to decide what to do.

Be careful: the input

```
$(\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{-5}{9})$
```

should be

```
$(\frac{2}{3},\frac{-5}{9})$
```

Also

```
$k^{*} < k < \frac{7}{3} \text{ with } k = 2$
```

should be

```
$k^{*} < k < \frac{7}{3}$ with $k = 2$
```

Comment: Thank you, I definitely missed that one. But I am getting another error that comes from the formatting of my table that says: " \end{tabularx}
                   
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| The inputgiven as a number does not make logical sense. This happens,
| forexample, if a number only contains a sign.
|...............................................
" After I made the corrections for the bugs

Comment: @PutsandCalls That's what I refer to with “the fourth cell in the second row”, that you specified as `S`, but has textual and not numeric content.

Comment: Ah I see it now, I will keep in mind the advice of commenting each line out.